# Why does the switch (single pole) in my bedroom have to be off or my closet lights switch (single pole) will not turn the closet lights on?

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, light, dimmer-switch

Note to those helping: I am new so I cannot answer your questions via comment (It says I don’t have enough points to comment) so I just keep editing the original question. Answers below.

Unless the switch in my bedroom (that turns on the overhead recessed bedroom lights) is in the off position my closet light switch does not function. My bedroom light switch is a dimmer switch wired for single pole, as there is only the one switch that controls the overhead lights. It works fine. Similarly, the closet light is a single pole light switch. It only works if the bedroom lights are off. If the bedroom lights are on, I am unable to turn on the closet lights. However, if I leave the closet switch in the on-position and turn the bedroom lights off, then on again, the closet lights will come on and then function normally.

Additional information: the bedroom light switch is housed with three other switches in the same box. The first in the series is a 3-way switch, followed by the single pole dimmer for the overhead recessed lights, and then the single pole switch that turns on the fan.

Answers to questions:
I do not know what the three-way switch goes to. I was told it controls an outlet, but I have not found that to be the case. There is the second three-way switch on another wall. It could also control the light on the fan but, there is no light installed on the fan, but I assume there is the option.

The red and white travelers off of the three-way switch going into their own cable with a black wire as well (which I missed the first time) that comes off the wire nut (diagram updated).

Yes, the the closet box is separate from the ones you see in the diagram and alone.

I missed one black cable as mentioned so wiring diagram is updated.

The other 3-way box is on another wall and wired exactly like the one on the diagram.

There are two light fixtures in the closet, I will get a picture and wire diagram of both the switch box as well as the fixture boxes tomorrow. Both closets have the exact same problem…both with dimmer switches, but I am just asking about one as certainly the origin is the same. The fixture wiring for each light is very straightforward with white to white, black to black and ground to ground (nothing unusual). Switches are also single pole…nothing odd there either.

[image: Updated Wiring Diagram]
[image: Inside Junction box]

[image: Inside Junction box 2]

[image: Wiring of switches]

Comment: Can you post clear photos of how all the switches are wired, including the connections in the backs of the switch boxes, please?

Comment: I take it the closet light switch is in a box by itself? Also, what does the three-way control, and what does the black wire in the cable carrying the travelers for that three-way connect to?

Comment: ... and also can you show similar photos and diagrams of the box where the closet light is and the box where the closet light switch is?   And can you do voltage and continuity tests between the cables in the three boxes?   It's a bit of a pain but I think you'll need to do that.  Build a full schematic of the wiring in this room.

Comment: Note that even when you _do_ have enough rep to comment, it is _much_ better to edit the question to include the requested information.  I wish more people would do it!

Comment: VtC because OP did not provide suggested details and has now modified the installation making it impossible to answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

White connected to the switch suggests that that wire is one of the three-way travellers. (Neutral is always white, white isn't always neutral.)

The only way I can make your scenario make sense would be if the room lights are the three-way, and the closet light was connected to one of the travellers (switched hot) rather than to an unswitched hot. This could be tested by flipping the other switch in the three-way pair (so the behavior of this one is reversed) and seeing if now the closet light only comes on when you turn the room light *on*.

At this hour I'm not going to try to untangle the wired in the photo and determine whether the error is here or elsewhere. With any luck, someone else will spot it... but it may be in the box housing the other three-way, or elsewhere on the closet light circuit.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, but it’s not the solution I was looking for. I replaced the dimmer with a single pole switch and that fixed the problem. I’ll do that with the other one and forgo the function of the dimmer. Thanks to all who tried to help.